# An attempt to use the sigpending function

Tags: c, signal-handling

I wrote a program that uses the `sigpending ()` function. The program returns blocked or pending signals.

My question is, what else could I improve or what problems does implementation have? Possible bugs?

code:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void catcher(int signum) {
    puts("inside catcher!");
    if (signum != 0)
        perror("signum error");
}

void check_pending(int signum, char * signame) {
    sigset_t sigset;

    if (sigpending( & sigset) != 0)
        perror("sigpending() error");
    else if (sigismember( & sigset, signum))
        printf("a %s signal is pending\n", signame);
    else
        printf("no %s signals are pending\n", signame);
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigset_t sigset;

    sigemptyset( & sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = 0;
    sigact.sa_handler = catcher;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, & sigact, NULL) != 0)
        perror("sigaction() error");
    else {
        sigemptyset( & sigset);
        sigaddset( & sigset, SIGUSR1);
        if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, & sigset, NULL) != 0)
            perror("sigprocmask() error");
        else {
            puts("SIGUSR1 signals are now blocked");
            kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
            printf("after kill: ");
            check_pending(SIGUSR1, "SIGUSR1");
            sigemptyset( & sigset);
            sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, & sigset, NULL);
            puts("SIGUSR1 signals are no longer blocked");
            check_pending(SIGUSR1, "SIGUSR1");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> what else could I improve or what problems does implementation have?

Just some little ideas.  Sorry, not much `sig...()` feedback.

---

**Lack of documentation**

At *least* some comments in the .c file to indicate overall functionality.

**Use `const`**

Use `const` to allow call with a `const char *` and to better convey function's use of `signame`.

```
// void check_pending(int signum, char * signame)
void check_pending(int signum, const char * signame)
```

**Clearer message**

Consider a *sentence* and not lower case.

Example below, but applies to other output as well.

```
// printf("a %s signal is pending\n", signame);
printf("A %s signal is pending.\n", signame);
```

From time-to-time and especially in error messages, it is really nice to see a *string* printed with sentinels (like quote-marks).  It is useful in seeing what part of output is format and what is data.

```
printf("A \"%s\" signal is pending.\n", signame);
```

In error message this in even more important as *something* went wrong.  Maybe the string has unexpected leading/trailing white-space that is messing up the operation?

**Fully initialize**

Consider these 2 code snippets.  The 2nd one fully initializes `sigact`- even members that are not obviously important.

```
// OP
struct sigaction sigact;
sigemptyset( & sigact.sa_mask);
sigact.sa_flags = 0;
sigact.sa_handler = catcher;

// Suggested
// This initializes all members, not just .sa_flags, .sa_handler.
struct sigaction sigact = { .sa_flags = 0, .sa_handler = catcher };
sigemptyset( & sigact.sa_mask);
```

**Define in needed block, not above**

```
// sigset_t sigset;
...
else {
    sigset_t sigset;
    sigemptyset( & sigset);
```

**Error check**

`kill()`, `sigprocmask()`, and other process functions deserve a check of their return values.

**Error return**

After `perror("sigprocmask() error");`, I'd expect a different return value like `return EXIT_FAILURE;` so calling scripts can differentiate.

**Style**

There are various *style* issues that I do not prefer like: missing `{}` on one-liners, `void`-less `main()`, spaced use of unary `&`, pointer `*`, 4-space indent.  Yet it is more important to employ a constant style than to promote *my* preference.  OP's code is consistent and that is good.

I do like subtle good style bits like alphabetized `include`.